# Does one "study" a perspective?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, collocation

Can a perspective be "studied"? And, what other verbs (e.g., understand, read, learn, etc.) can be associated with "perspective" on matters relating to knowledge?

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine an educated native English speaker “studying a perspective”. Please provide an example sentence.

Comment: There are few examples from educated native English speakers: 1.)https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0264837713000483 2.)https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4724167/

Comment: But I agree, it sounded weird to me as well. That is why I wanted to know what others thought about it.

Comment: Yes, my native English-speaking scientific colleagues have blood on their hands. But I did my best with my own students — even had them in tears at times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your general question, here's a raw list of the top 100 verbs that collocate with *perspective* according to the Corpus of Contemporary American English:

```
 1                   PUT          793         
 2                   HAVE         431         
 3                   GET          327         
 4                   IS           315         
 5                   KEEP         258         
 6                   'S           241         
 7                   PROVIDE      202         
 8                   HAS          181         
 9                   GIVE         167         
10                   GAIN         144         
11                   PROVIDES     137         
12                   HAD          125         
13                   OFFERS       116         
14                   BE           110         
15                   TAKE         102         
16                   PUTS          97         
17                   BRING         94         
18                   OFFER         91         
19                   CHANGED       90         
20                   VIEWED        88         
21                   GIVES         79         
22                   CHANGE        76         
23                   SEEN          69         
24                   LOSE          61         
25                   UNDERSTAND    59         
26                   CAN           57         
27                   OFFERED       56         
28                   PUTTING       52         
29                   THINK         51         
30                   TAKING        48         
31                   WAS           48         
32                   TOLD          46         
33                   ADOPT         43         
34                   GIVEN         43         
35                   LOST          43         
36                   SHARE         43         
37                   BRINGS        42         
38                   GAVE          42         
39                   GOT           38         
40                   KEPT          38         
41                   BROUGHT       37         
42                   GAINED        36         
43                   MAINTAIN      36         
44                   WRITTEN       35         
45                   SEE           34         
46                   ARE           33         
47                   PROVIDING     33         
48                   USING         33         
49                   APPRECIATE    32         
50                   ADD           32         
51                   HEAR          32         
52                   CHANGES       30         
53                   NEED          30         
54                   SHIFT         30         
55                   BROADEN       29         
56                   DEPENDS       29         
57                   PRESENTS      29         
58                   DEVELOP       28         
59                   WILL          28         
60                   ADOPTING      27         
61                   GAINING       27         
62                   GETTING       27         
63                   ADDS          26         
64                   GIVING        26         
65                   CONSIDER      24         
66                   DO            24         
67                   PROVIDED      24         
68                   SHARED        24         
69                   TAKES         24         
70                   KEEPING       23         
71                   OFFERING      23         
72                   'LL           22         
73                   FIND          22         
74                   USE           22         
75                   BRINGING      20         
76                   CHANGING      20         
77                   HELP          20         
78                   PLACED        20         
79                   DEVELOPING    19         
80                   EXAMINED      19         
81                   HAVING        19         
82                   KNOW          19         
83                   NEEDED        19         
84                   DEVELOPED     18         
85                   REGAIN        18         
86                   DOES          17         
87                   LACK          17         
88                   LOSING        17         
89                   REFLECT       17         
90                   ADOPTED       16         
91                   PLACE         16         
92                   REFLECTS      16         
93                   REQUIRES      16         
94                   UNDERSTOOD    16         
95                   WOULD         16         
96                   AGREE         15         
97                   BASED         15         
98                   BEEN          15         
99                   COULD         15         
100                  MAY           15
```

Regarding your specific question, yes you can *study* a perspective, but the more idiomatic choice would be *examine*, *explore*, or *(try to) understand*. As can indeed be verified by perusing the list above.